# ffmpeg Build Output is not showing?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on Ffmpeg last couple of days but unable to get any valuable output.
       After that I follow bellow tutorial :-
       http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/
      According to that tutorial. Once it’s done, you should be able to find a folder 
       `$NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android`, which contains `arm/lib` and `arm/include` folders.
       But I am not getting build output in `$NDK/sources/ffmpeg-2.0.1/android`.
       Please anyone  help me.

thanks.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting my 2 days I have successfully compile this for this follow bellow link
   its quite good.

http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Developing_Multimedia_Applications_with_NDK.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In your build_android.sh, just make the ./configure commandline one long string instead of breaking it up. The spaces between each option is messing with the parser.

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/home/hwlab/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
    ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-avdevice --disable-doc --disable-symver --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile --sysroot=$SYSROOT --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
    make clean
    make
    make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```