# How to build ffmpeg in android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

After successfully build ffmpeg by bellow steps

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471514/ffmpeg-build-output-is-not-showing

  Now I have copy include and all .a file into my JNI folder. and my Android.mk 
  file is as:-



      LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

        include $(CLEAR_VARS)

        LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpegutils
       LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial02.c

      LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
      LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(NDK_PLATFORMS_ROOT)/$(TARGET_PLATFORM)/arch-arm/usr/lib -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -lavformat -lavcodec  -lavfilter -lavutil -lswscale -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -ldl -lgcc

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

but my project giving error as:-

```
     Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libffmpegutils.so] Error 1 MainActivity            C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost'    MainActivity        line 231, external location: /home/kiwitech/Documents/development/tools/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpegutils/tutorial02.o: in function decodeAndRender:jni/tutorial02.c   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_lock' MainActivity        line 222, external location: /home/kiwitech/Documents/development/tools/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpegutils/tutorial02.o: in function decodeAndRender:jni/tutorial02.c   C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_release'  MainActivity        line 150, external location: /home/kiwitech/Documents/development/tools/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpegutils/tutorial02.o: in function naSetSurface:jni/tutorial02.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry'   MainActivity        line 147, external location: /home/kiwitech/Documents/development/tools/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpegutils/tutorial02.o: in function naSetSurface:jni/tutorial02.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_fromSurface'  MainActivity        line 145, external location: /home/kiwitech/Documents/development/tools/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpegutils/tutorial02.o: in function naSetSurface:jni/tutorial02.c  C/C++ Problem
```

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must link with the android library too, so add -landroid to your LOCAL_LDLIBS.

The document STABLE-APIS.html under $NDK/docs explains:

> All the corresponding functions are provided by the "libandroid.so" library version that comes with API level 9. To use it, use the following:
>       LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

Comment: which android library please can you modify my .mk file

Comment: Hi, Please describe reason ,because its work.thanks lot

Comment: @SandeepTiwari You have a linker error indicating that it can't find any of these symbols, so you need to find out which NDK library provides these functions. A good starting point is always the document STABLE-APIS.HTML in the directory $NDK/docs. Read the section "The Android native application APIs" and you will find the answer to your question.